# problem on booting of linux

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel

I had installed Linux on my laptop which is dual boot and contains SSD and HDD both. And I had completely installed Linux on SSD and all goes fine.

But sometimes when I turn on the laptop the logo flashed only with some random stuff on the screen.

I tried to solve the problem but none of the works.

here is the picture of words that come repeatedly.

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVuEf.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peggO.jpg)

I am using

elementary OS 5.0 Juno
Linux 4.15.0-47-generic
GTK+ 3.22.30

and my system is

Dual-Core Intel® Core™ i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz
Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
8.1 GB memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had this same problem and here's how I solved it,
Go to tty mode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>,
if you can't, insert a live cd then get into `chroot`, try to reinstall your `plymouth` but before reinstalling the `plymouth`, try to reconfigure the `plymouth` first,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure plymouth && sudo update-initramfs -u
```

if it doesn't work. then reinstall it,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth
```

Comment: thanks for answer , I had done this lets see in next reboot

Comment: it looks like worked